# Can't manipulate height of background in semantic-ui

Tags: css, user-interface, background-image, semantic-ui

I'm using a template from semantic-ui. This one: https://semantic-ui.com/examples/homepage.html. Essentially i'm trying to change the height of the background to match the height of my image. Right now my image (the one in background-image) shows up but the background (which I turned red simply to see it better) is larger then it so I have this dead space between my background-image and the beginning of the content.

The only way I seem to be able to manipulate the background is the color. Any other time i'm changing it's size (which i've experimented with quite a bit) it only seems to change the size of the image. Not the red background.

Perhaps i'm not understanding the relationship between the two? Any tips on how to change the background's height to match the background-image?

Any help is appreciated.

CSS below:

```
   .ui.inverted.vertical.center.aligned.segment {
        background: red; 
        background-image: url('./images/backgroundLogo.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* background-size: 100%; */
        background-size: 100% 507px;;
        width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. There was a native min-height: property that was over riding my attempts to change. Simply put in

```
min-height: 500px !important;
```

and it worked.